# Leer/Escribir caracteres especiales del español (acentos, ñ,...) en una aplicación de consola C

Tags: c, codificación

Estoy tratando de que una aplicación de consola de C recoja (mediante teclado) caracteres especiales del español como acentos, 'ñ', etc en un `scanf` o en `gets`.

He conseguido que se muestren dichos caracteres correctamente (almacenados en una variable o, directamente, desde el `printf`) gracias al paquete `locale.h`. Muestro un ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Añade paquete de idiomas
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Declaración de variables
    char cadena[254];

    // Establecer el idioma a español
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");

    // Mostrar correctamente los caracteres especiales del español
    printf("¡Éxito!. Se muestran los caracteres especiales del español.");

    printf("Introduce un string con caracteres especiales: ");
    gets(cadena);

    printf("El string con caracteres especiales que has introducido es: %s", cadena);

    return 0;   
}
```

pero aún no conseguí que se recojan correctamente con las funciones mencionadas arriba.

¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo?

Gracias

---

**EDIT 1:**

Haciendo pruebas he observado que:

- **`setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");`** Muestra los caracteres del español correctamente, pero no los recoge desde teclado.
- **`setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");`** Recoge los caracteres del español correctamente desde teclado, pero no los muestra bien.

Comment: No veo el problema... He compilado y ejecutado ese programa bajo Ubuntu y el segundo `printf()` muestra correctamente lo que he leido (lo que no es de extrañar, porque lo que lees realmente es una cadena de bytes que el printf vuelca de nuevo tal cual a consola, con lo que el mismo encoding que se haya usado para el input se usará para el output). ¿Cómo te has conectado a la consola? ¿Directamente, o vía ssh? ¿Con qué cliente?

Comment: Directamente, usando CodeBlock Debugger. Le he hecho un EDIT a la pregunta, es algo muy extraño, no debería de haber problema como comentas, pero lo hay... y no entiendo el por qué

Comment: Entonces estás en un entorno windows? No sé si los locale POSIX están soportados. En cualquier caso, prueba con `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`

Comment: Si, exacto, estoy corriendo el programa sobre Windows. He probado eso que comentas y no recoge correctamente los caracteres especiales. El primer printf lo muestra correcto. El segundo no

Comment: Bueno a lo que e visto en el programa me muestra X cuando muestro el valor y si lo muestro como numérico me sale 2686386 eso es lo que sale JuMoGar ?

Comment: Cómo? no entiendo lo que me comentas. A que te refieres? qué valor?

Comment: compile tu programa y me sale un 'x' y no la 'ñ'

Comment: ah! vale, a mi me sale como una especie de sol, un carácter raro

Comment: ya me funciono tienes que quitar `setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");`  y si te acepta la ñ

Comment: Si lo quitas acepta la ñ,  pero el primer printf te saldrá con símbolos raros,  no? O al menos,  ese es mi caso

Comment: en mi caso no todo sale bien

Comment: Creo que lo que falta aquí es `wprintf` y `wchar` ...

Comment: @NaCl He estado probando eso que comentas de `wprintf` y `wchar` y no me está funcionando. De todas formas, no busco esa 'solución', si no con un printf normal y un gets.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

He encontrado una solución al problema. Al parecer, este problema sólo aparece en Windows y su consola de comandos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Añade paquete de idiomas
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Declaración de variables
    char cadena[254];

    // Establecer el idioma a español
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish"); // Cambiar locale - Suficiente para máquinas Linux
    SetConsoleCP(1252); // Cambiar STDIN -  Para máquinas Windows
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1252); // Cambiar STDOUT - Para máquinas Windows

    // Mostrar correctamente los caracteres especiales del español
    printf("¡Éxito!. Se muestran los caracteres especiales del español.");

    printf("Introduce un string con caracteres especiales: ");
    gets(cadena);

    printf("El string con caracteres especiales que has introducido es: %s", cadena);

    return 0;   
}
```

Consiste en cambiar la codificación tanto de entrada como de salida de la consola de windows con los comandos `SetConsoleCP()` y `SetConsoleOutputCP()` (para ello es necesario también incluir la cabecera `windows.h`). Con eso se resuelve el problema. Espero que sea de ayuda a otras personas que tengan el mismo problema que yo.

Un saludo.

Comment: +1. Solo añadir, que, sino me equivoco, el problema en Windows radica en que la interfaz de las aplicaciones usa una codificación distinta a la codificación utilizada en la consola. Más exactamente, la primera utiliza la codificación [1252](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195054.aspx), mientras que la consola hace uso de la codificacion [850](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195064.aspx).