# ¿Cómo mostrar cadenas con caracteres especiales del español en win32 api?

Tags: c, api, windows, caracteres, unicode

Estoy programando algunos ejemplos del Petzold (5a. ed, win32 api en C) y no logro compilarlos cuando añado acentos u otros caracteres del español dentro de las cadenas. El ejemplo funciona perfectamente si la cadena no tiene acentos.

Estoy compilando en [codeblocks](/questions/tagged/codeblocks)+[mingw](/questions/tagged/mingw), con la instalación por default (más la opción `-lgdi32` en el linker) en una máquina [windows10](/questions/tagged/windows10).

El error es:

```
error: converting to execution character set: Illegal byte sequence
```

y la línea con error es:

```
static TCHAR cadenaNombreDeLaAplicacion[] = TEXT ("MétricaSistema");
```

Código:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK ElProcWin (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM); // WndProc

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE handlerInstanciaPrograma, HINSTANCE handlerInstPrevia,
                    PSTR cadenaLineaDeComandos, int enteroComoSeMuestraLaVentana
                    )
{
    static TCHAR cadenaNombreDeLaAplicacion[] = TEXT ("MétricaSistema");
    HWND handleDeVentana;
    MSG mensajeParaLoop;
    WNDCLASS claseVentana; 

    claseVentana.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
    claseVentana.lpfnWndProc    = ElProcWin ;
    claseVentana.cbClsExtra     = 0 ;
    claseVentana.cbWndExtra     = 0 ;
    claseVentana.hInstance      = handlerInstanciaPrograma;
    claseVentana.hIcon          = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION) ;
    claseVentana.hCursor        = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
// hay que añadir -lgdi32 en other linker options para GetStockObject
    claseVentana.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH) ; 
    claseVentana.lpszMenuName   = NULL ;
    claseVentana.lpszClassName  = cadenaNombreDeLaAplicacion;

    if (!RegisterClass (&claseVentana))
    {
        MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("No corre en versiones anteriores a NT!"),
                    cadenaNombreDeLaAplicacion, MB_ICONERROR); 
        return 0 ;
    }

    handleDeVentana = CreateWindow (cadenaNombreDeLaAplicacion,
                                    TEXT ("Metricas del sistema"),
                                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,          
                                    CW_USEDEFAULT,                
                                    CW_USEDEFAULT,                
                                    CW_USEDEFAULT,                
                                    CW_USEDEFAULT,                
                                    NULL,                         
                                    NULL,                         
                                    handlerInstanciaPrograma,
                                    NULL                          
                                    );
    ShowWindow (handleDeVentana, enteroComoSeMuestraLaVentana); 
    UpdateWindow (handleDeVentana) ;                            

    while (GetMessage (&mensajeParaLoop, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage (&mensajeParaLoop) ;
        DispatchMessage (&mensajeParaLoop) ;
    }
    return mensajeParaLoop.wParam ;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ElProcWin (HWND handleVentana, UINT mensajeRecibido, WPARAM wParametro, LPARAM lParametro) 
{
    HDC         handleContextoDeDispositivo ;
    PAINTSTRUCT estructuraDePintar;
    RECT        rectangulo;

    switch (mensajeRecibido)
    {

    case WM_PAINT: 
        handleContextoDeDispositivo = BeginPaint (handleVentana, 
                  &estructuraDePintar) ;
        GetClientRect (handleVentana, &rectangulo) ;

        DrawText (handleContextoDeDispositivo, TEXT("Hola Windows 10!"), -1, 
                  &rectangulo,
                  DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER) ; 

        EndPaint (handleVentana, &estructuraDePintar) ;
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY: 
        PostQuitMessage (0) ;
        return 0 ;

    }
    return DefWindowProc (handleVentana, mensajeRecibido, wParametro, 
                          lParametro) ; 
}
```

Comment: eso es lenuaje c?

Comment: Sí, es prácticamente el "Hola Mundo" de la  API win32  del Petzold.

Comment: Habríá que ver cómo entregarle un parámetro como el `-finput-charset` de gcc al compilar, para decirle que use algo diferente a ascii

Comment: @Ignorante he actualizado las etiquetas, espero que eso ayude a que tu pregunta tenga mas atención de la gente indicada

Comment: En teoría necesitas convertir de UTF8 (en `char*`) a UTF16 (en `wchar*`).  https://stackoverflow.com/a/504789/13419694

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probando un poco llegué a la conclusión de que el error ocurre por la codificación del archivo ya que los caracteres con acentos no forman parte de la codificación por defecto.

Para cada archivo ve a **Edit** > **File encoding** y selecciona **UTF-8** y guarda el archivo.

Con eso el problema debería estar solucionado.

Si te sigue apareciendo, prueba borrando los caracteres especiales, guardando el archivo y luego volviéndolos a escribir. También puedes usar Visual Studio Code para asegurarte de que el código se ve bien para la codificación seleccionada.

---

Mí hipótesis es que la codificación por defecto [del compilador es **UTF-8**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12217048/13419694) mientras que la codificación del código fuente es diferente y causa el error.

Comment: ¡Es verdad! Funciona con UTF-8. Muchas gracias :-)
Entonces es un problema del codeblocks, ciertamente.

Comment: @Ignorante A mí me parece menos un probleme de code::blocks, mas de MinGW. No he probado, pero esta solucíon podría ser non-portabil, MSVC podría indroducir el mismo problema otra vez *ahora*.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a usar la función setlocale, pon esta instrucción al principio de la función WinMain:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
```

A lo mejor tienes que importar la librería locale.h también.

He encontrado este enlace por si te sirve:
[Leer/Escribir caracteres especiales del español (acentos, ñ,...) en una aplicación de consola C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151363/leer-escribir-caracteres-especiales-del-espa%c3%b1ol-acentos-%c3%b1-en-una-aplicaci)